# How to intersect mutliple list with Lambda Expression?

Tags: c#, lambda, intersect

I have a few list. Their count isn't clear.

For example (for 4 list):

```
List1   List2    List3     List4 
-----   -----    -----     -----
  1       2        3         4
  2       4        8         3   
  3       8        4         5   
  4       11       6         1    
  5       3        7         7    
  6       9        11        9
```

I want to find the items that are common. It can do with T-SQL in MSSQL.

The result will be like that:

```
ResultList : (3, 4)
```

How is it done with Lambda Expression ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable.Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx)

```
var commonItems = list1.Intersect(list2).Intersect(list3).Intersect(list4);
```

Answer (score 2):

For an arbitrary number of lists, you would do something like this:

```
var List<List<int>> lists; //This contains the lists I assume...
var result = lists.Skip(1).Aggregate(lists.First(), (accum, cur) => accum.Intersect(cur));
```

Comment: Thanks @GregRos, I already had the intersection solved but was about ready to do some hardcoding for arbitrary number of lists. This was just the piece I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

```
list1.Intersect(list2).Intersect(list3).Intersect(list4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [`Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Enumerable.Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx) and intersect List1 with List1 and its result with List3 and so on.

```
    List1.Intersect(List2).Intersect(List3).Intersect(List4)
```